# What does it mean and how to fix Ansible error " 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' "?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I am trying to install MySql 5.7 version through Ansible, but it is saying

```
fatal: [192.168.1.45]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Failure downloading http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm, 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'"}
```

To fix the issue i tried setting up proxy in the environment section, but still it is failing.
Below is the script, through which I am trying to install MySQL

```
---
- hosts: dbservers
  remote_user: yabx
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: Install MySQL 5.7 repo
      yum: name=http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm state=present

    - name: Install MySQL 5.7
      yum: pkg={{ item }}
      with_items:
      - mysql-community-server
      - mysql-community-client
      - MySQL-python

    - name: Start the MySQL service
      service: name=mysqld state=started enabled=true

    - name: Change mysql root password and keep track in
      shell: |
        password_match=`awk '/A temporary password is generated for/ {a=$0} END{ print a }' /var/log/mysqld.log | awk '{print $(NF)}'`
        echo $password_match
        mysql -uroot -p$password_match --connect-expired-password -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'PassW0rd'; flush privileges; "
        echo "[client]"
        user=root
        password=PassW0rd > /root/.my.cnf
      args:
        creates: /root/.my.cnf
      register: change_temp_pass
      notify: restart mysqld

    - meta: flush_handlers
    - debug:
        var: change_temp_pass

  handlers:
    - name: restart mysqld
      service:
        name: mysqld
        state: restarted
      environment:
        http_proxy: http://***:***@192.168.1.45:8080
        https_proxy: https://***:***@192.168.1.45:8080
```

I want MySQL to be installed on my RHEL 7.4 through Ansible script.

Answer (score 0):

## Foreword

- Do yourself a favor and adopt the modern yaml only syntax for ansible module parameters in your tasks. It is easier to read, less error prone, and will let linters (e.g. [yamllint](https://pypi.org/project/yamllint/)...) capture more errors earlier.
- As explained in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html), don't use loops with the `yum` module. This will process each package individually. Instead, send the list of packages directly to the `name` parameter.

My examples below are following those 2 rules.

## Actual answer

You have set the proxy environment only for your handler task to restart mysql

If you have several tasks that need a proxy and that it is ok to set it everywhere (e.g. even for tasks that don't need it), you can do it at play level

```
---
- name: Install and configure mysql
  hosts: dbservers
  remote_user: yabx
  become: true

  environment:
    http_proxy: http://***:***@192.168.1.45:8080
    https_proxy: https://***:***@192.168.1.45:8080
    no_proxy: .my-company.com, .my-other-internal-site.com

  tasks: 
    # ... tasks all executed with above env...
```

If this is not ok, then you need to define the proxy on each task that needs it (the yum tasks in your case). You can however use a play (or iventory) var to make the writing more concise:

```
---
- name: Install and configure mysql
  hosts: dbservers
  remote_user: yabx
  become: true

  vars:
    my_proxy_env:
      http_proxy: http://***:***@192.168.1.45:8080
      https_proxy: https://***:***@192.168.1.45:8080
      no_proxy: .my-company.com, .my-other-internal-site.com

  tasks: 
    - name: Install MySQL 5.7 repo
      yum:
        name: http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm
        state: present
      environment: "{{ my_proxy_env }}"

    - name: Install MySQL 5.7
      yum:
        name:
          - mysql-community-server
          - mysql-community-client
          - MySQL-python
      environment: "{{ my_proxy_env }}"

   # ... other tasks without proxy ...
```